# How to make class cd-words-wrapper 535px instead of 435px in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Been trying for hours to make the Javascript on the class cd-words-wrapper wider than 435px. Ideally 535px? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is the section of code that controls the event

```
    function showWord($word, $duration) {
    if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
        showLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, false, $duration);
        $word.addClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden');

    }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
        $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({ 'width' : $word.width() + 10 }, revealDuration, function(){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, revealAnimationDelay); 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').css({'width':'535px'})

Comment: Thank you.Now how do I place this in the code without breaking it. I'm a newbie. ;/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late response, but I had some trouble with my work.

With `jquery` you can chain (or not) your methods an selectors, to make this clear for you here is the example without chaining:

You can do:

```
function showWord($word, $duration) {
    if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
        showLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, false, $duration);
        $word.addClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden');

    }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
        $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').css({'width':'535px'});
        $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({ 'width' : $word.width() + 10 }, revealDuration, function(){ 
            setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, revealAnimationDelay); 
        });
    }
}
```

But you can also do this:

```
function showWord($word, $duration) {
        if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
            showLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, false, $duration);
            $word.addClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden');

        }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {

            $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').css({'width':'535px'}).animate({ 'width' : $word.width() + 10 }, revealDuration, function(){ 
                setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, revealAnimationDelay); 
            });
        }
    }
```

NOTE: I didn't have checked of the rest of your code is correct of is working correctly, but because you do not ask for it I suppose it is.

If you really want to learn `jquery` search for some beginners tutorials and you will learn it in no time.

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thank you again. I tried both but no love. I have already started my jQuery classes a day or two ago. Here is a link to the project in beta > http://oz2digital.com/UMHC/ You'ii see that in Chrome the lasted word in the rotation pushes way down due to the width and if the adjust the CSS the script just down sizes the container. Tahnk you for your help!